# setting trasparency in ggplot2 using aes_color_fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this few lines in order to plot some boxplots, and everything works:

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=DOY_S1, y=S1_VV, alpha=0.5, fill="S1", group=paste(fileIn$DOY_S1, sep=""))) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=DOY_RS2, y=RS2_VV, alpha=0.5, fill="RS2", group=paste(fileIn$DOY_RS2, sep=""))) +
scale_fill_manual(name="Sensor", values=c("S1"="brown", "RS2"="grey"))
```

but I would like to define the trasparency in scale_fill_manual.
In google I found this solution, but doesn't work

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn)+
geom_boxplot(aes(x=DOY_S1, y=S1_VV, fill="S1",group=paste(fileIn$DOY_S1, sep=""))) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=DOY_RS2, y=RS2_VV, fill="RS2", group=paste(fileIn$DOY_RS2, sep=""))) +
scale_fill_manual(name="Sensor", values=alpha(c("S1"="brown", "RS2"="grey"), 0.5))+
```

can you help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: please add `dput(fileIn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `alpha` in the geom:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(setosa = "blue",
                               versicolor = "green",
                               virginica = "red"))
```

The transparency is adopted for the legend automatically.

Of course, you can also map a variable to a transparency scale with `aes`.

Comment: Thank you Roland, this is how I solved my problem   plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn) +
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5, aes(x=DOY_S1, y=S1_VH, fill="S1", group=paste(fileIn$DOY_S1, sep=""))) +
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.5, aes(x=DOY_RS2, y=RS2_VH, fill="RS2", group=paste(fileIn$DOY_RS2, sep=""))) +
    scale_fill_manual(name="Sensor", values=c("S1"="brown", "RS2"="grey"))+